# WinAPI call to locate a command on the systems path & environment?

Tags: windows, api, file, path

I recall seeing an API call or a .NET function where for example if I Start->Run

cmd.exe

it would search the %path% until it locates cmd.exe

So that API would look like

String path = GetFullPathOrWhatever("cmd.exe")
// RESULT would be: c:\windows\cmd.exe OR WHEREVER THE SYSTEM WOULD FIND IT

Any ideas which API does this search?

Answer (score 1):

[SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: hi no its not that one, it was something like FindOnPath it looked at the %path% environment to resolve the full path it would use for an exe typed at the command line

Comment: It does look in the system path -- from the Remarks section: "If the lpPath parameter is NULL ... When the value of this REG_DWORD registry value is set to 1, SearchPath first searches the folders that are specified in the system path, and then searches the current working folder. When the value of this registry value is set to 0, the computer first searches the current working folder, and then searches the folders that are specified in the system path."

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [SearchPath function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?